# Launch app via NFC and send a NDEF message back when started

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, ndef, android-beam

I'm developing an Android app which interacts with other devices using NFC. This interaction consists of 2 steps basically:

1. When the device receives a specific URI by NFC from other device, the app is launched.
2. When the app starts, it sends a NDEF message back to the other device.

For the first step, I have added the following lines to the *AndroidManifest.xml* file. That way, the `MainActivity` will be launched when the device receives a URI of type `myprotocol:something`:

```xml
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:scheme="myprotocol" />
 </intent-filter>
```

For the second step, my `MainActivity` class implements `CreateNdefMessageCallback` and `OnNdefPushCompleteCallback`. The code looks like following:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    NfcAdapter adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    adapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);
    adapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(this, this);
}

@Override
public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {
    NdefRecord uriRecord = NdefRecord.createUri("protocol:something");
    NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { uriRecord });
    return message;
}

@Override
public void onNdefPushComplete(NfcEvent event) {

}
```

So, now **the problem**:

These two parts work fine independently, but not when I add both to the app.

That is, if I add the first part, the app is correctly launched when receiving the NDEF message. Also, if I only add the second part, if I tap my device to other device while running the app, I see *Touch to beam* interface, and the NDEF message is sent.

The problem is, that if I add both, when tapping to the other device, the app is launched, but the *Touch to beam* interface is never shown. If I separate the devices and tap again, the `MainActivity` is relaunched, but I never get to see the option to send the message.

How could I achieve the desired scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-tap approach is not possible using Beam on two Android devices (note that with other devices, particularly if one is Android and one is a dedicated NFC reader or a device where you can control the NFC functionality on a low level or a device that emulates an NFC tag).

However, a two-tap approach is possible between two Android devices with only little modifications to your existing scenario. You simply need to add a foreground dispatch that intercepts your incoming NDEF message and consequently prevents Android from restarting your activity:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    NfcAdapter adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
            0);
    adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pi, null, null);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

A more general approach for the two-tap scenario would be to send the NDEF message from device A to device B on the first tap. This NDEF message starts the app on device B. Immediately after sending the NDEF message, device A stop sending the message. When the app on device B is active, it registeres its own NDEF message for Beam. Then, in the second tap, the Beam UI will be shown on device B and clicking the Beam screen will send the response NDEF message to device A.

Note that device A must stop sending its initial NDEF message. Otherwise, the app on device B will receive a new NDEF message and, consequently, won't open the Beam UI.

Comment: I have tried it, but I never get to see the "Touch to beam" screen. I keep getting the Activity on top.

Comment: I've just tried your example and it had exactly the result I expected (even without the foreground dispatch): app is running on device A, homescreen on device B; tap the two devices; Beam UI is shown on device A; click Beam; app is launched on device B; tap devices again; Beam UI is shown on both devices; click Beam on device B. So I obviously must have misinterpreted your question. Could you clarify what you actually expected to happen?

Comment: Ok, I've realized, that the problem in my case is that Device A (not an Android phone in my case) keeps on publishing the first message, which causes the app in B being relaunched when tapped for second time. I have solved my problem by stopping to publish the message after it is sent on first step. But, anyway, is there any way to prebent the Android app from being relaunched if it is in foreground?

Comment: Okay, now I believe I understand your problem: Without the foreground dispatch, your activity will start over and over. With the foreground dispatch, your activity will not be started over and over but the Beam UI isn't displayed either due to the other device already initiating a Beam operation. So what is the other device?

Comment: The other device is a Windows Phone device or a Tablet running Windows 8. If I stop publishing the NDEF message from the other device, once step 1 has concluded, then I see the Beam UI if I tap the devices again.