# Send NDEF messages without touching the device

Tags: android, nfc

Is it possible to send NDEF message without having to touch the device?

For example, when it receives a message, it automatically send back a reply.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266944/launch-app-via-nfc-and-send-a-ndef-message-back-when-started

Comment: Thanks! @AmarbirSingh